# MAMP Community edition Magento 2 installation issues PHP Extension intl. missing

Tags: php, apache, magento, mamp, ini

[Magento 2.2.2 on MAMP 3.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVOWU.png)

I saw a similar question to this but the solution was for XAMPP and not MAMP.

I have already tried to uncomment `extension=php_intl.dll` in my php.ini file located at `C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.5` to no avail. I have restarted both my servers and my machine after the changes were made. I then tried to change `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` to -1 as [Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html) suggest, still no results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try repeating the same updates on the file C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.5\conf\php.ini

MAMP server picks the php.ini file from the path MAMP\bin\ directory.